# How to obtain raw TimeTicks with SharpSnmp?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, sharp-snmp

I'm trying to monitor system up time by using #snmp (Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.9.0.1) and C#.

Here's my code:

```
        public int GetUptime()
    {
        var uptimeMessage = new GetNextRequestMessage(0, VersionCode.V1, new OctetString("public"),
            new List<Variable>
            {
                new Variable(new ObjectIdentifier(Oids.SystemUpTime))
            });
        var response = uptimeMessage.GetResponse(10000, _agentEndPoint);
        var ticks = response.Pdu().Variables[0].Data.ToString();
        return int.Parse(ticks);
    }
```

But i'm getting a CS0103 error when trying to get .Data property for a response of type TimeTicks.

Here's the Inspection Window of VS2015
[image]

If this is not a bug, how can i access raw ticks value using #snmp ?

Comment: Looks like something in `Data` is trying to access the non-existent `count` when it should be accessing `_count`.

Comment: @Nomada Just out of interest is Oid.SystemUpTime a dotted oid string or string oid? Am looking to convert a string oid to its dotted oid equivalent. Any code example would be great.

Comment: @Joseph Oids is a static class with const strings: For example: 
`public const string SysUpTime = "1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3";`
`public const string SystemUpTime = "1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.1";`

Comment: @Nomada oh cool, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By checking the source code of `TimeTicks` in this library you can see the `ToString` method in fact generates a string based in .NET `TimeSpan`. That's why when you try to parse it as `int` exceptions come.

As for this OID you already know the `Data` would be a `TimeTicks` you should cast to that type and then call `ToUInt32`.